# jQuery re-direct to page on MouseOver Looping

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to re-direct or load a page on moveover or hover, the code below works just fine for what I'm trying to do, however if you keep the move over the link it loops and keeps reloading the page, how do I stop it from looping constantly when hovering over the links?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container").css("background", "");
    $(".container").fadeIn(500);
    $("#side-menu ul li a").hover(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      linkLocation = this.href;

      $(".container").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
    });


    function redirectPage() {
      window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems with the code and one with the strategy:

**Problem 1** As @FloydThreepwood pointed out, you should be using `mouseenter`.  `hover` will fire when your mouse enters and leaves the area. `mouseenter` only fires when you enter.

**Problem 2** You're binding `mouseenter` before jQuery has had a chance to deal with the existing mouse events.  After ready calls, it will see that the mouse is over an object and call `mouseenter` on that object.  You can nullify this first event by encasing your code in `$('body').one('mouseover', function() {...});`  In this setup, the initial `mouseenter` event will fire and propagate down to the body.  The body event will then be able to create the mouse events without worrying about that initial firing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').one('mouseenter', function() {
        $(".container").css("background", "");
        $(".container").fadeIn(500);
        $("#side-menu ul li a").mouseenter(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;

            $(".container").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
        });
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

**Problem 3** You should never ever be doing something like this.  In this design, a user could accidentally move their mouse across the page and start a new page load.  It also severely reduces the accessibility to users who may be using a screenreader or other device.  You could have *cancelable* actions that affect only a *portion* of the page, like a hover preview, but you should never have a navigation action based simply on the user moving their mouse.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help that worked perfectly, and yes I agree with you on problem 3 however this is a page that uses links as image previews because there are more then just images on the page and the user would moveover to revel new items, descriptions, etc

Comment: Actually there's a weird effect when after a while the on hover effect disappears, is there a way to always keep it the effect happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead.